# Change the custom text ( Comment · Like· Share) when posted on profile page using facebook share functionality

Tags: facebook

I have a facebook iframe application with share functionality. Currently when i share something its showing the custom text Comment · Like· Share when posted on profile page.

I want to give customized text like view result etc.

How can i achieve this please guide me ?

I am using the code

```
<script>function fbs_click() {u='<?php echo $shareURL;?>';t=document.title;window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(u)+'&t='+encodeURIComponent(t),'sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436');return false;}</script><style> html .fb_share_button { display: -moz-inline-block; display:inline-block; padding:1px 20px 0 5px; height:15px; border:1px solid #d8dfea; background:url(http://b.static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/z … 8q506x.gif) no-repeat top right; } html .fb_share_button:hover { color:#b5b8d3; border-color:#295582; background:#3b5998 url(http://b.static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/z … 8q506x.gif) no-repeat top right; text-decoration:none; } </style> <a href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=<url>" class="fb_share_button" onclick="return fbs_click()" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;">Share</a>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Facebook's dialogs you can specify custom action links with your posts, but if you're using the old sharer.php this isn't possible.